# Adding JRE 7 to eclipse on mac osx after upgrading to app-engine 1.7.7

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have been developing an app with the GAE-Eclipse-plugin. I just updated eclipse to app-engine 1.7.7. So that launched a whirlwind of errors that I have been walking thru. I finally figured that I need to install `jre7`. So I went to http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/44788/java-se-runtime-environment-7 and installed the jre. Then I try to link eclipse to the jre by going thru `eclipse > preferences > java > installed JREs`. There I only saw Java SE 6. So I clicked on `MacOS X VM` then browsed to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/`. When I got there I expected to find `1.7`. But instead, after `1.6.0` I see `A`, `Current`, `CurrentJDK`.

Is the correct version missing from the list or which one of those three am I to select otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

You are installing the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE), which just updates the browser plugin (/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java).  You want to install the Java Development Kit (JDK).  I always go to Oracle directly, but here's the [MacUpdate link](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/45571/java-se-development-kit-7).

Once it's installed you should see it under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk.  Eclipse should see it, but if you want to use it by default you will need to either update your java links in /usr/bin (not recommended) or update your eclipse.ini file (${eclipse.home}/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini) to [point to the new JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: Link to Oracle download: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Please note the difference is java 7 can be found at **/Library/Java** whereas the built-in Java SE 6 JRE mentioned by the asker is at **/System/Library**

Comment: You should also check out this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6) because Eclipse (at least Kepler in my experience) keeps prompting for a Java 6 install.