# How can I launch eclipse mavericks from the doc

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, dock, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install eclipse on maverick. I've installed Oracle java 1.7 and can launch eclipse using the link I found in the untared eclipse directory. However, when I pin the icon to the mac dock, trying to open eclipse using that icon results in 'Software Update' telling me 'To open "Eclipse," you need a java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?'

I guess that this method of launching is somehow not using the eclipse.ini file in which I have used the -vm option to specify that eclipse be launched using the oracle 1.7 version of java on my system.

Anyone know how I can fix this? I wondered if I can edit a config file for the doc entry similar to the way I can add items to ubuntu's launcher perhaps?

Comment: Just let it install Java 6. Most people are finding that it still uses Java 7 after doing this.

Comment: same problem here, need a fix,  I don't want to install java 1.6 once  I have 1.7

Comment: The solution for me has been to allow java 6 to install. I can confirm that once java 6 is installed eclipse is actually run using java 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by running Apple's Mavericks Java fix. Even though the fix claims to install Java 6 it ended up just reconfiguring my already installed Java 7 and Eclipse is now able to run normally from the dock and command line. My default JVM is still java 7.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest version of 1.7?

Oracle's Java version 7u25 and below have been disabled by Apple on OS X.

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml

Comment: Yes, I have java version "1.7.0_45". Eclipse runs perfectly when run using the link that launches Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse, but not when I pin the resulting eclipse icon to the dock and they try to use that to launch eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ah,your question solves me . After I update my MAC OS X to mavericks,I can not open my eclipse .I use "open Eclipse.app" or click eclipse on dock .It doesn't work .says"your need java se 6 runtime"

Then I follow your advice ,run "Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse",greet! I open it.

It seems this is the only way to run eclipse on mavericks~

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaky suspicion that I have a fix for this, but as my system has 1.6 in already I can't test it at the moment.

In the eclipse.ini file you will find the following vm arg; -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 I have a suspicion that if you changed this line to
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 
you might find that you could launch eclipse without the need for java 6. OSGi is the technology that Eclipse uses to manage and run its plugins.

The location of eclipse.ini is dependent on the system but on a Mac you can find it in /Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.in.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this fix (without having Apples Java 1.6 installed) didn't work for me.