# Eclipse does not recognize Java 7 on Mavericks, can't find jdk.1.7.0_51 to fix issue

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks

Now, the problem of not being able to use Java Development Kit 7 with eclipse on Mac computers seems to be a problem a lot of people have. After digging around, I found what seemed to be a widely accepted solution here: [Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6/)

The problem is, there are no files in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. I enabled hidden files but still found nothing. I looked around for more solutions, but they all seem to involve the jdk.1.7.0_xx file. I have tried reinstalling java (downloaded from the java site) multiple times but no files appear.

Now, I could try installing Java 6, but it's kind of a pain to download on a 30kbps internet connection, so I would prefer if there was another way. Plus, it's concerning that a file that everyone else seems to have is missing.

So, my question is: Is there any way I can acquire this file (separate download, something I missed, etc) or do I have to download Java SE 6? Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you download, from where? The Oracle download for the JDK is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) jdk-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg

Comment: I downloaded from Oracle, but the filename of the file I downloaded is jre-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg (jre instead of jdk.) You think that's the problem?

Comment: If you want to do Java development you need the JDK. Since I do development I always use the JDK and don't have any experience with just using the JRE.

Comment: Well, that's it then. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: I've downloaded the JDK (8), installed it, and if I check "java -version" on the command line I got back version 8. However eclipse still cannot find it.