# Several applications on Mavericks OS X requesting install Java 6 SE runtime, but already have Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, osx-mavericks, aptana3

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6) thread about it, but after I followed the instructions I got this error when trying to open eclipse

```
The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol
```

And this one for AptanaStudio3

```
Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
I really don't want to have to install Java 6.

Comment: Did you verify that a) the plist file is a valid xml file containing the appropriate additions and that b) your java installation is actually working/not corrupted?

Comment: I checked b), but where is the plist for aptana?

Comment: Just to verify, you installed the Oracle JDK 7 or 8 and followed my instructions in the answer you originally linked?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot for a second, but yes, I edited the plist file  inside the jdk1.7.0_40 folder AND the jdk1.7.0_51 folder. Actually I am just now wondering why there are two folders when the Java Control Panel in System Preferences only lists the 1.7.0_51...

Comment: Mh, an update/upgrade shouldn't cause that, at least that was never my experience. You could try removing the JDK fully and reinstalling, fixing the plist and check whether that work.

Answer (score 0):

You only need Java 6 installed for all of Apple's proprietary APIs. This gives applications access to native Mac OS X functionality like Cocoa, Objective-C stuff, and various OS services. It's also used for accessing Mac OS JNI code. I'm not sure if the Oracle JDKs provide JNI on Mac OS, but it's possible the only way to get that is through Apple's JRE/JDK (which they've stopped developing for some reason).

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't want Java 6. Using it will create more problems than it fixes for me. For example, I'm using Netbeans 8.0 in lieu of eclipse, which requires Java 7. Others seem to be able to use Java 7 with eclipse, so there must be a fix.