# Eclipse Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks

I just installed Mac OSX Mavericks (10.9.2). Installed JDK 1.7.0_55. Everything seems to be installed properly. 
I downloaded Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 and unzipped to my Applications folder. Again I've double checked the installation. 
When I start the Application, I get the following error message:

```
Eclipse quit unexpectedly.
```

I checked my Console Output and I get the following in the Eclipse Error Report:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c

What I've done so far:
-Tried changing JVMCapabilities like in this post [Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6) .
-Tried with JDK 1.8
-Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere

I am new to Mac hence it might be a simple Code 18 but I would greatly appreciate any Input 
to help me resolve this.

Etienne Pilon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emptied the thrash and then launch from the terminal and it works. I believe I copied the folder to my Application folder from the Downloads and then moved it to thrash instead of simply dragging the folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:**
When you finished the unzip of Eclipse, then go to Application folder and double click on eclipse-inst-mac64.dmg and the process of eclipse will begin. After installation simply open the eclipse and it will work.