# issue setting up eclipse on mac osx mavericks

Tags: java, android, macos, jvm, osx-mavericks

I have a Macbook pro running OSX Mavericks that I'm attempting to setup for Android development.

1. I downloaded the standard version of Luna Eclipse.
2. I then downloaded and installed Java 7.
3. I then attempted to open Eclipse and it wanted to download a Java 6 SE?(I think) version which it did and installed.
4. Then it told me `Version 1.60_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required`.

What else do I have to install/upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest java version. Then you can download Eclipse ADT from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html which will include eclipse and android SDK.

You can also download Android Studio instead of Eclipse, android sdk is also included in the package.

After all open android SDK Manager and download api-s that you need.

Comment: If I download the Eclipse SDK from that link can I uninstall Java 7?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Eclipse wants Java 7 ('Version 1.7'), but OS X demands that you have Java 6 ('Version 1.6') installed in order to use Java applications. So, Eclipse starts, sees Java 6, then quits and tells you to upgrade to Java 7. If you use Java 7, OS X won't let you start Eclipse.

The fix is to install Java 7 (which you already have), uninstall Java 6, then symlink Java 7 to where OS X expects to find Java 6.

As per [this link](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~simpkins/teaching/gatech/cs2340/guides/java7-macosx.html), the procedure goes like this:

```
# Remove Java 6
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
sudo rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.JavaForMacOSX*
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo rm /Library/Java/Home
# Symlink Java 7
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home /Library/Java/Home
```

(I'm not at my Mac to try this, but I had to do this to get Eclipse to work myself)

Comment: Can't recall, but this fix may also have been required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6

Comment: I ended up just installing Eclipse from the other answers link. As a requisite it had a link to JDK 6 which I installed and now its working. Unfortunately I had already removed the Java 7 install so I can't confirm if this would fix it.