# Run eclipse mac os x

Tags: java, macos, configuration

I have installed java se 7u71 but running eclipse show the below dialog

[image].

Comment: And?  Seems pretty obvious to me...

Comment: is their some kind of thing like setting JAVA_HOME

Comment: You don't have a Java 6 runtime to run Eclipse.

Comment: but i have installed java se 7u71 yesterday and verified it from java web site

Comment: and java is also visible in preferences of system

Comment: Did you install Java 6? Because that's the version you need. Hit 'Install'

Comment: but i already have java 7 installed as per this requirment https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_10_10.xml

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` environment set to `jdk installation folder`? And is your `PATH` variable set to `bin` directory?

Comment: how can i check is that set or not @Aditya

Comment: It means you haven't set it. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are active discussions here

Check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only/58841#58841
and this thread
[Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't set your environment variables yet.

Open your terminal and type this

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

You can set your environment variables here.

Press `i` once the file opens up.

Suppose your jdk installation folder is:

```
/Library/Java/jdk1.7/
```

Type this in the file opened in your terminal:

```
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/jdk1.7" 
PATH=$PATH:"$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: vim ~/.bash_profile  after typing this command in shell vim ~/.bash_profile and pressing i --INSERT-- showed up but no place to type the following 2 lines

Comment: You need to type on the terminal and then press control+c and type `:wq` to save the file.