# Java Application not running on OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, osx-yosemite, rweka

After installing OS X Yosemite, one of my Java Applications stopped running. The message was that I needed JAVA SE 6 Runtime. Exactly as in [Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6)

I did as user Nikolas suggested and apparently had the same problem as user Sage commented:

Initially, this gave me the Eclipse error `Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine`, but that was because my `/usr/bin/java` was symlinked to another 1.7 (the /Library/Internet/... plugins one instead of the /Library/Java... one). After fixing that link, this works beautifully for me - I wish I could give two upvotes! –  sage Dec 28 '13 at 0:43 "

This is what Terminal says after trying to run it:

```
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
[JavaAppLauncher Error] JNI_CreateJavaVM() failed, error: -1
logout

[Process completed]
```

Anyone can advice me on how to go around this issue?

Comment: I'm not certain about OS X, but Eclipse has an `eclipse.ini` file that can have a reference to the version of Java it is to run under. You may need to find and update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [here](http://oliverdowling.com.au/2014/03/28/java-se-8-on-mac-os-x/), there's an update for El Capitan. The updated solution, that worked here, would be:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries
Password:
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve the problem creating links as seen here http://oliverdowling.com.au/2014/03/28/java-se-8-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: This problem occurs when installing the R package RWeka on El Capitan.  The answer posted here addresses the RWeka install failure, though you need to close R Studio and re-open it for the change to be effective.